# Using REST, SOAP or JSON with Google OpenID or OAuth

Tags: json, web-services, rest, google-openid, google-oauth

Is there any way that I can use REST, SOAP or JSON to authenticate users using Google OpenID or Google OAuth? The server that I'm required to use is very incompatible with PHP (rendering the existing OpenID and OAuth libraries for PHP useless) and I don't foresee it being worth the trouble of installing PHP and making sure that it's working to verify users using PHP. I'd rather make users create their own account for my website than use PHP to verify their Google account (because this project will be internal to my company).

Is there any web service out there that would allow me to use REST, SOAP or JSON to verify a user using Google OpenID or OAuth?

Comment: Gigya has a webservice implementation that allows google login capabilites to website. Gigya also has server side api.

Answer (score 2):

Google's implementation of OAuth 2.0 is RESTful and uses JSON in the body of requests/responses. The documentation for the OAuth flow and all of the parameters can be found at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer. After authenticating your application will have an access token and refresh token as JSON parameters. The access token is sent as an Authorization header to access the end resources, and the refresh token is used in the body of requests to refresh the access token.